# How to speed up my python code working with DB?

Tags: python, sql, database, loops, google-bigquery

I have a question about working with huge amount of data. I am working with Google Big Query (i don't think it is a problem of this DB) and need to SELECT data from one table, change it (using python) and then INSERT to another table. Could you tell me, how can i speed up these operations. I use the **for** loop for each row of my SELECT command. And working with only 15k rows is very long-time process. Maybe multithreading or some libraries could help me to do *EXACTLY the same function* to all of my >15k rows in DB. Thanks.

Comment: Try multiprocessing. Select your rows in the main "driver" part of your program and place them on a queue. Have multiple sub-processes each of which consume messages from the queue, modify the data and perform the DB insert. Without seeing any code from you it's hard to give specific advice

Comment: @LancelotduLac, thank you. I will try it. But it could not be a problem with data if it is inserted into a table in the parallel way? Like two rows inserted at one time.

Comment: DBMS is designed to support concurrency. You don't need to worry about multiple processes attempting concurrent inserts or, indeed, any other activity. That's why you have a database rather than having to write code that has to manage flat files and concerns over concurrency. Go ahead. Try it

Answer (score 0):

Missing some details about the process (which DB server is it ?)

Anyway, The best approach would be:

- Fetch by buffering: **dbChunk** = "DB Cursor".fetchmany(buffer_size)
- Change the data in Python  Data structures (LIST) ==> dbChunk2
- Load into second table, using "DB Cursor".executemany(InsertString, **dsChunk2**)

  - **dsChunk2** is the updated LIST item where data was fetched into ([ (...), (...), ... ])

you can tune the buffer_size to get the best results. (start with 1000,I think)

Note: InserString should be included Columns, Values and bind variables - match to the Select statement.

Comment: If I understand you clear, creating a list in python an then INSERT the whole list is better than INSERTing all the list data with one line at a time.

Comment: You understand correctly. Batch execution is much faster in data processing.